# Selenium 3.6.0 & webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities) - deprecated?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

Since upgrading to the latest version of Selenium the following code seems to be deprecated:

```
Selenium 3.6.0 & webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities) - deprecated?
```

Full code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);   //deprecated
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/rb/CHANGES

```
3.4.1 (2017-06-13)
==================
Firefox:
  * Added new Firefox::Options class that should be used to customize browser
    behavior (command line arguments, profile, preferences, Firefox binary, etc.).
    The instance of options class can be passed to driver initialization using
    :options key. Old way of passing these customization directly to driver
    initialization is deprecated.
```

From the 3.4.1 version the FirefoxOptions should be used.

Answer (score 7):

Changed the following code '`FirefoxDriver(capabilities)` to `firefoxOptions` which uses `.setCapcability()`

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
    webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how your answer solves the problem, code samples help, but explanation helps others understand why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this line;

```
FirefoxOptions ffOpt = new FirefoxOptions();
ffOpt.setCapabilities("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOpt);
```

Comment: Is that java code? Then you are probably missing some `new` keywords

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```